# Каким средством получить settings.ini удобнее, с содержимым в виде словаря и несколькими переменными?

Tags: python

Необходимо записать словарь и переменные в файл settings.ini, (** если файл отсутствует, создать его)

*Заготовка словаря:*

```
dict1 = [
    {'object': 'label', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'button', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'color', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'line', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'unknown', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
]
```

*Переменные:*

```
theme = light
icon_size = 32
indent = 36
```

*Вопрос:*

Каким образом удобней всего это сделать?
config parser, yaml или json? (важно чтобы файл назывался именно "settings.ini")

Comment: Я бы честно попробовал как INI записать: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: попытка записать dict1 как переменную заканчивается ошибкой. строка записи: cfg['section']['option'] = dict1, ошибки: self._parser._validate_value_types(option=key, value=value)
in _validate_value_types
    raise TypeError("option values must be strings")
TypeError: option values must be strings

Comment: наличие словаря         dict1     это принципиальное требование ?

Comment: да, обязательное, либо сделать аналог, (**хочу из словаря циклом производить неизвестное количество выборок для добавления button, label и line на панель)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так записать:

```
import configparser

dict1 = [
    {'object': 'label', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'button', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'color', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'line', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'unknown', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
]

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config['DEFAULT'] = {'theme': 'theme', 'icon_size': 32, 'indent ': 36}

for d in dict1:
    config[d['object']] = d

with open('example.ini', 'w') as f:
    config.write(f)
```

Считывание из ini:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.ini')

print(dict(config['DEFAULT']))
# {'theme': 'theme', 'icon_size': '32', 'indent': '36'}

for section in config.sections():
    print(dict(config[section]))

# {'object': 'label', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command', 'theme': 'theme', 'icon_size': '32', 'indent': '36'}
# {'object': 'button', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command', 'theme': 'theme', 'icon_size': '32', 'indent': '36'}
# {'object': 'color', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command', 'theme': 'theme', 'icon_size': '32', 'indent': '36'}
# {'object': 'line', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command', 'theme': 'theme', 'icon_size': '32', 'indent': '36'}
# {'object': 'unknown', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command', 'theme': 'theme', 'icon_size': '32', 'indent': '36'}
```

Файл `example.ini`:

```
[DEFAULT]
theme = theme
icon_size = 32
indent  = 36

[label]
object = label
icon = icon
icon_hover = icon_hover
command = command

[button]
object = button
icon = icon
icon_hover = icon_hover
command = command

[color]
object = color
icon = icon
icon_hover = icon_hover
command = command

[line]
object = line
icon = icon
icon_hover = icon_hover
command = command

[unknown]
object = unknown
icon = icon
icon_hover = icon_hover
command = command
```

Comment: как тогда записать переменные theme = light, icon_size = 32 и indent = 36, таким образом чтобы не перепуталось с остальным списком?

Comment: Запишите в `DEFAULT`: `config['DEFAULT'] = {'theme': theme, 'icon_size': icon_size, 'indent ': indent}`

Comment: так мне нужно будет еще это все считать, причем отдельно...

Comment: так как теперь произвести считывание этого словаря из файла?

Comment: @biomotor, я же вам прикладывал документацию, там все написано :) Добавлю в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Запись в файл:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import configparser

dictionary = [
    {'object': 'label', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'button', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'color', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'line', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
    {'object': 'unknown', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'},
]

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config['default'] = {'theme': 'theme', 'icon_size': 32, 'indent ': 36}

for d in dictionary:
    config[d['object']] = d

with open('example.ini', 'w') as f:
    config.write(f)
```

Чтение из файла:

```
with open('example.ini', 'r') as f:
    config.read(f)

dictionary = []
for s in config.sections():
    section = {}
    for k in config[s]:
        v = config[s][k]
        section.update({k: v})
    if s == 'default':
        settings = section
    else:
        dictionary.append(section)

print(dictionary)
print(settings)
```

Результат:

```
[{'object': 'label', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'}, {'object': 'button', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'}, {'object': 'color', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'}, {'object': 'line', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'}, {'object': 'unknown', 'icon': 'icon', 'icon_hover': 'icon_hover', 'command': 'command'}]
{'theme': 'theme', 'icon_size': '32', 'indent ': '36'}
```